# Is there any way to convert json to xml in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, json

Is there any way to convert `json` to `xml` in `PHP`? I know that xml to json is very much possible.

Comment: And even more important: Why would you ever want to do that?

Comment: `$xml = "<xml><![CDATA[$json]]></xml>";`  (Ask a silly question…)

Comment: The Zend Framework has a very well working [component](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.json.xml2json.html) for this.

Comment: @NikiC Legacy support and that XML has many features that don't yet exist for JSON, for example XPATH and XSLT

Answer (score 26):

If you're willing to use the [XML Serializer](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer) from PEAR, you can convert the JSON to a PHP object and then the PHP object to XML in two easy steps:

```
include("XML/Serializer.php");

function json_to_xml($json) {
    $serializer = new XML_Serializer();
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    if ($serializer->serialize($obj)) {
        return $serializer->getSerializedData();
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It depends on how exactly you want you XML to look like. I would try a combination of [`json_decode()`](http://us.php.net/json_decode) and the [`PEAR::XML_Serializer`](http://pear.php.net/XML_Serializer) ([more info and examples on sitepoint.com](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/xml-php-pear-xml_serializer/)).

```
require_once 'XML/Serializer.php';

$data = json_decode($json, true)

// An array of serializer options
$serializer_options = array (
  'addDecl' => TRUE,
  'encoding' => 'ISO-8859-1',
  'indent' => '  ',
  'rootName' => 'json',
  'mode' => 'simplexml'
); 

$Serializer = &new XML_Serializer($serializer_options);
$status = $Serializer->serialize($data);

if (PEAR::isError($status)) die($status->getMessage());

echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars($Serializer->getSerializedData());
echo '</pre>';
```

(Untested code - but you get the idea)

Comment: Ack, ya beat me by half a minute. I'll leave mine up anyway - it's a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 8):

Crack open the JSON with `json_decode`, and traverse it to generate whatever XML you want.

In case you're wondering, there is no canonical mapping between JSON and XML, so you have to write the XML-generation code yourself, based on the needs of your application.

Answer (score 5):

I combined the two earlier suggestions into:

```
/**
 * Convert JSON to XML
 * @param string    - json
 * @return string   - XML
 */
function json_to_xml($json)
{
    include_once("XML/Serializer.php");

    $options = array (
      'addDecl' => TRUE,
      'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
      'indent' => '  ',
      'rootName' => 'json',
      'mode' => 'simplexml'
    );

    $serializer = new XML_Serializer($options);
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    if ($serializer->serialize($obj)) {
        return $serializer->getSerializedData();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect for me Cheers

Answer (score 3):

A native approch might be

```
function json_to_xml($obj){
  $str = "";
  if(is_null($obj))
    return "<null/>";
  elseif(is_array($obj)) {
      //a list is a hash with 'simple' incremental keys
    $is_list = array_keys($obj) == array_keys(array_values($obj));
    if(!$is_list) {
      $str.= "<hash>";
      foreach($obj as $k=>$v)
        $str.="<item key=\"$k\">".json_to_xml($v)."</item>".CRLF;
      $str .= "</hash>";
    } else {
      $str.= "<list>";
      foreach($obj as $v)
        $str.="<item>".json_to_xml($v)."</item>".CRLF;
      $str .= "</list>";
    }
    return $str;
  } elseif(is_string($obj)) {
    return htmlspecialchars($obj) != $obj ? "<![CDATA[$obj]]>" : $obj;
  } elseif(is_scalar($obj))
    return $obj;
  else
    throw new Exception("Unsupported type $obj");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a [JSON streaming parser](https://github.com/search?l=PHP&p=2&q=json%20parser&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories).

Using a streamer parser would come in handy if you want to bypass the intermediate object graph created by PHP when using `json_decode`. For instance, when you got a large JSON document and memory is an issue, you could output the XML with [`XMLWriter`](http://php.net/xmlwriter) directly while reading the document with the streaming parser.

One example would be https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

```
$writer = new XMLWriter;
$xml->openURI('file.xml');
$listener = new JSON2XML($writer); // you need to write the JSON2XML listener
$stream = fopen('doc.json', 'r');
try {
    $parser = new JsonStreamingParser_Parser($stream, $listener);
    $parser->parse();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    fclose($stream);
    throw $e;
}
```

The JSON2XML Listener would need to implement the [Listener interface](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser/blob/master/src/JsonStreamingParser/Listener.php):

```
interface JsonStreamingParser_Listener 
{
  public function start_document();
  public function end_document();
  public function start_object();
  public function end_object();
  public function start_array();
  public function end_array();
  public function key($key);
  public function value($value);
}
```

At runtime, the listener will receive the various events from the parser, e.g. when the parser finds an object, it will send the data to the `start_object()` method. When it finds an array, it will trigger `start_array()` and so on. In those methods you'd then delegate the values to the appropriate methods in the `XMLWriter`, e.g. [`start_element()`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.xmlwriter-start-element.php) and so on.

**Disclaimer:** I am not affiliated with the author, nor have I used the tool before. I picked this library because the API looked sufficiently simple to illustrate how to use an event based JSON parser.