# Parse weird formatted data to XML?

Tags: php, json, xml, parsing

Sample output data is below, it looks something like JSON, but it's not formatted exactly like JSON. So I am wondering, how can I get this data looking like XML, preferably with php?

```
[{
  action: 'getallregions',
  reply: [{
    regionid: '1',
    name: 'Blue',
    description: 'Research Route',
    color: '508CEB',
    active: 'true',
    parentRegionId: '0',
    parentRegion: ''
  }, {
    regionid: '4',
    name: 'Green',
    description: 'Vet School Route',
    color: '73BE69',
    active: 'true',
    parentRegionId: '0',
    parentRegion: ''
  }, {
    regionid: '10',
    name: 'Purple',
    description: 'Loop route',
    color: '5300B5',
    active: 'true',
    parentRegionId: '0',
    parentRegion: ''
  }]
}]
```

Here is the data on Pastie.org http://pastie.org/1045154

Comment: Here is the data on Pastie.org
http://pastie.org/1045154

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ross, you can just edit your question rather than adding that comment. I'll fix this one for you. :)

Comment: That looks like javascript arrays

Comment: Also, the data is basically JSON - it's either incorrectly formatted JSON (because it's incorrectly quoted), or it's just a Javascript object literal.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in topic "[Is there some way to convert json to xml in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856833/is-there-some-way-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-php)"

Hope, that it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but:

```
json_decode(preg_replace('/([a-z0-9]+):/i','"$1":',str_replace('\'','"',$data)))
```

Basically I found a way to make the input valid JSON. The you can convert the object to xml using the XML_Serializer.