# how do i install json in xampp server?

Tags: json, xampp

How do I install json in xampp server?

Comment: do you mean a php extension ???

Comment: Ravi: Did you know: You can edit your question, so include this information in your question to improve it. Another hint that might help you get better votes and more answers: Go to your old questions and *accept* the answer to each that helped you most (by clicking on the checkmark besides it.

Answer (score 3):

Json is a [format](http://www.json.org/); you don't install it, you implement it.

---

If you want to use the json format in your php website, there's an extension that provides [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) you can use to [encode data in a json format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

To install or use the extension, please see the [installation page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.installation.php); depending on your version of php you may have the json extension already bundled with xampp. If you've got the [latest version](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) of xampp (windows install), it's ok to use the methods directly

Comment: how to implement it in my xamp server.how i run json in my xamp server?

Comment: It is a data format, you don't run it any more than you run a text document or a photo.

Comment: i use json for convert my sql data into xml.so how i convert it?

Comment: You can't use JSON to convert SQL data into XML (since it is, as might have been mentioned already, a data format and not a programming language). You could, in theory, use it as an intermediary format, but that sounds like a waste of time.

Comment: @Ravi: you write a php script to convert data into json format which will then be sent to javascript to process, check the php function json_encode() for a reference

Comment: samy: Your answer is great (+1), it covers both the correction of Ravi's understanding on what JSON is as well as tips concerning the add-in he seems to be speaking of and contains many helpful links. However your second sentence you added is a little bit confusing because you don't tell that you start to speak about an add-in now. You might want to add some words there, e.g.: "If you're speaking about the JSON add-in: Depending on your version..."

Comment: my xamp version is 1.6.4

Comment: @chiccodoro: thanks for the advice, i edited the answer. @ravi: your install of xampp contains two versions of php (4.4.7 and 5.2.4); you must use the 5.2.4 to benefit from the bundled json extension. If you use the 4.2.7 version, either change versions or install the extension following the link i posted

Comment: sorry my xamp version is 5.2.4

Comment: thanks for reply.how i covert that json result into xml?

Comment: convert json to xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/856833/is-there-some-way-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1):

Xampp is "shipped" with Apache, MySQL, PHP, Perl and support for JSON in PHP and Perl!

[**Json PHP**](http://php.net/manual/de/book.json.php)

**Json Perl:** `JSON::to_json(hash);`

Simple [PHP **example** from php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
<?php
$arr = array ('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>3,'d'=>4,'e'=>5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

**EDIT:** Second example showing how to json_encode() a mysql query result:

```
<?php
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT ...");
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

**EDIT 2:** You are then able to convert JSON to XML using one of the described methods from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856833/is-there-some-way-to-convert-json-to-xml-in-php).

**Edit3:** If you want to save the xml file to disc use

```
$myFile = "file.xml";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$data = x;           // replace x with the xml from your ajax result !!!!!
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: thanks.but how can i get array from query?

Comment: i edited my post showing an example

Comment: thanks for reply.i put json to xml code below to first step?

Comment: you first get the data from the databse then you put everything into a json object and then you convert it to xml

Comment: thanks for reply.i see the xml result in browser but xml file is not create.how to generate xml file.

Comment: do you want it to save to disc?