# XML instead of json

Tags: php, xml, api, curl, response

I am trying to connect to an API with an XML response. I have it working in json (see below) but i need it to return in xml instead.

```
//check if you have curl loaded
if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");

$url = 'http://api.klout.com/1/klout.xml?users=username&key=keyhere';

$ch=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$r=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($r,true);

foreach($arr['users'] as $val)
{
        echo $val['kscore'].'<br>';
        echo $val['twitter_screen_name'].'<br>';
}
```

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: See this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/856887/201648. Not quite what you're doing, but should solve your problem. Short answer, PEAR XML Serializer should help http://pear.php.net/package/XML_Serializer. If you can post a sample of the curled data I can take a crack at it for you, although I'm going to bed in a minute.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "I have it working in json". Have you successfully decoded a JSON response from that service and want to decode an alternate XML response from the same service? After reading other responses I've realised this statement is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The API you are using returns data in XML format. So, you cannot use `json_decode()` to parse it, obviously. Instead, you should look to **[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)**. It's the default PHP library to parse and write XML data, and usually it comes installed by default with PHP.

You can start with this nice tutorial:

> http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-To-SimpleXML-With-PHP.html

Or if you want to start very very quickly:

> http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml.asp

It's very easy to use it to parse XML data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is what i have now and I cannot get it to work no matter what. `<?php
    // set feed URL
    // add category
    $feedURL = 'http://api.klout.com/1/klout.xml?users=chris_till%2Ciamchristill&key=e8mpa7nj6dnc8f97aufu78vk';
    // read feed into SimpleXML object
    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

 foreach($sxml->users->user->kscore as $a){
   echo $a;
 }
 ?>` Thanks, Chris

Comment: @ChrisTill I can't help you because I cannot get XML (I have a *Not Authorized* response). PHP gives you errors or what? I would be glad to help you, so if you can paste both PHP code and XML response content somewhere (i.e. *[PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/)*)...