# Convert JSON to XML in php

Tags: php, xml, json, zend-framework

I would like to convert a `JSON` object directly to `XML`.
I know, I can use Pear and/or other function(s) to convert it into native `PHP` and then convert to `XML` but I want to know if there is any way to directly convert it to `XML` from `JSON`.

Preferably using the `Zend Framework`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: try the code in this link: http://blog.djekldevelopments.co.uk/?p=362

Comment: the dupe is phrased in a way that would include this question. Since there was no answer illustrating how to convert JSON to XML bypassing PHP's intermediate object graph, I've added one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17528125/208809

Comment: I don't understand why this was marked as a dupe?  Shouldn't have been.  Similar question, sure, but this one was asking about the ZEND Framework, and the answers in the "already answered in" question didn't mentioned ZEND at all.